how to display woocommerce cart items in form and mail using contact form 7?
I have this code to create a custom tag for display woocommerce cart items in cf7 form and send cart items in email notifications. But in Email I can't figure out how show cart items like they are displayed in the form: with image product, name product, price ect.
In email I was only able to show products list in a boring and no acceptable way.
As extra, I also create a custom tag to display total cart excluding tax and without shipping amount (because is a quote request).
This is my working code.
// add "cart" tag in Contact Form 7
add_action('wpcf7_init', 'cartTag');

function cartTag() {
  wpcf7_add_form_tag('cart', 'cartItems', true);
}

// loop for cart items in "cart" tag Contact Form 7
function cartItems($tag) {
  if (is_null(WC()->cart)) {
    wc_load_cart();
  }
  $name = $tag['name'];
  if (empty($name)) {
    return '';
  }
  $items = WC()->cart->get_cart();
  $output = '<div class="my-cf7-cart">';
  $inputValue = "";
  $cart = [
    'total' => WC()->cart->total,
    'products' => []
  ];
  foreach ($items as $item => $values) {
    $_product = wc_get_product($values['data']->get_id());
    $item_image = $values['data']->get_image(array(0, 30));
    $price = wc_get_price_excluding_tax($_product);
    $price = $values['line_total'];
    $price = number_format($price, 2, ",", ".");
    $output .= '<div class="my-acf-cart-item"><a href="' . $_product->get_permalink() . '" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">' . $item_image;
    $output .= ' <p class="prev-product-title">' . $_product->get_title() . '</p></a>';
    $output .= '<p>Quantity: ';
    $output .= $values['quantity'] . '</p>';
    $output .= '<p>Price: € ' . $price . ' exc. tax</p></div>';

    // for email (CF7)
    $inputValue .= 'Product: ' . $_product->get_title() . ' &bull; Quantity: ' . $values['quantity'] . ' &bull; Price: € ' . $price . ' exc. tax &#x00A;';
    $cart['products'][] = [
      'name' => $_product->get_title(),
      'qty'  => $values['quantity'],
      'price' => $price,
      'link' => $_product->get_permalink()
    ];
  }

  // set total cart without shipping amount
  $total = WC()->cart->subtotal_ex_tax;
  $shipping = WC()->cart->shipping_total;
  $total = number_format($total, 2, ",", ".");
  $output .= '<p class="prev-total"><b>Products total:</b> € ' . $total . ' exc. tax</p>';

  $output .= '<input type="hidden" name="' . $name . '" value="' . $inputValue . '" />';
  $output .= '<input type="hidden" name="products" value="' . htmlspecialchars(json_encode($cart)) . '" />';
  $output .= '<input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="' . $_GET['shipping_method'] . '" />';
  $output .= '</div>';
  return $output;
}

// add "total" tag in Contact Form 7
add_action('wpcf7_init', 'totalTag');

function totalTag() {
  wpcf7_add_form_tag('total', 'totalItem', true);
}

// Total exc. tax in "total" tag Contact Form 7
function totalItem($tag) {
  if (is_null(WC()->cart)) {
    wc_load_cart();
  }
  $name = $tag['name'];
  if (empty($name)) {
    return '';
  }
  $output = '<div class="total-cart-excTax">';
  $total = WC()->cart->subtotal_ex_tax;
  $total = number_format($total, 2, ",", ".");
  $inputValue = '€ ' . $total . ' exc. tax';
  $output .= '<input type="hidden" name="' . $name . '" value="' . $inputValue . '" />';
  $output .= '</div>';
  return $output;
}

cart items list in my form
cart items list in my email
Thanks for any help
As suggested by Snuffy, I replaced this line of code:
$item_image = $values['data']->get_image(array(0, 30));

in:
$item_image = $_product->get_image();

I delated 'Thumbnail' because I don't like to have cropped product image.
It's a better way to write clean code, although the result doesn't change and that doesn't answer my question.
The portion of code I would like to implement is the following (complete code above):
// for email (CF7)
$inputValue .= 'Product: ' . $_product->get_title() . ' &bull; Quantity: ' . $values['quantity'] . ' &bull; Price: € ' . $price . ' exc. tax &#x00A;';
$cart['products'][] = [
  'name' => $_product->get_title(),
  'qty'  => $values['quantity'],
  'price' => $price,
  'link' => $_product->get_permalink()
];

The problem I like to fix is transform the input string in a kind of array, as in front end form appear built with this function (complete code in my question):
// loop for cart items in "cart" tag Contact Form 7
function cartItems($tag) {
  if (is_null(WC()->cart)) {
    wc_load_cart();
  }
  $name = $tag['name'];
  if (empty($name)) {
    return '';
  }
  $items = WC()->cart->get_cart();
  $output = '<div class="my-cf7-cart">';
  $inputValue = "";
  $cart = [
    'total' => WC()->cart->total,
    'products' => []
  ];
  foreach ($items as $item => $values) {
    $_product = wc_get_product($values['data']->get_id());
    $item_image = $values['data']->get_image(array(0, 30));
    $price = wc_get_price_excluding_tax($_product);
    $price = $values['line_total'];
    $price = number_format($price, 2, ",", ".");
    $output .= '<div class="my-acf-cart-item"><a href="' . $_product->get_permalink() . '" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">' . $item_image;
    $output .= ' <p class="prev-product-title">' . $_product->get_title() . '</p></a>';
    $output .= '<p>Quantity: ';
    $output .= $values['quantity'] . '</p>';
    $output .= '<p>Price: € ' . $price . ' exc. tax</p></div>';
//...
}

Same question not solved here: Contact form 7 custom tag not send
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

since $_product is object of product you can get product thumbnail from $_product->get_image('thumbnail'); or $_product->get_image_id() if you need the id only.

Thanks Snuffy for your comment, but I'm not able to figure out how rewrite the code that display in CF7 email the cart items like I have in the form. I attaced images to clarify the point and the problem I have to solve.

$item_image = $values['data']->get_image(array(0, 30)); doesnt make any sence. Replace it with $item_image = $_product->get_image('thumbnail');
